# VBA - If date past dont copy & Imporvements

Tags: excel, vba

First of all thanks for any help.

I have created a vba script to copy data from one sheet to another based on date, the reason for this is the data that is coming in will only show 10 days from yesterday, we have no control over this. because of this i need to copy each day across and preserve the data.

So on Sunday i can See Saturday data, so need to copy this across, on Monday i would no longer be able to see Saturday data so unable to copy, what i need to be able to do is copy each day across but if the date passes stop copying. So on Sunday i can copy Sat to Fri, on Mon stop copying sat and copy Sun to Fri and so on.

The data input changes all the time, hence why i need to copy each day.

So far i have managed to setup to copy each day, might not be the most efficient so any changes is welcome.
Where im stuck is figuring out the date part when to stop, guess using if date is date + 2 then ignore ?

i will also be looking to merge all the days again into 1 sheet to be able to pull the data out.

Below is the code i have so far.

Thanks again.

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim Last_Row As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

PerfDate1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F1").Value
PerfDate1 = Format(PerfDate1, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate1 = CDate(PerfDate1)

PerfDate2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F2").Value
PerfDate2 = Format(PerfDate2, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate2 = CDate(PerfDate2)

PerfDate3 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F3").Value
PerfDate3 = Format(PerfDate3, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate3 = CDate(PerfDate3)

PerfDate4 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F4").Value
PerfDate4 = Format(PerfDate4, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate4 = CDate(PerfDate4)

PerfDate5 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F5").Value
PerfDate5 = Format(PerfDate5, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate5 = CDate(PerfDate5)

PerfDate6 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F6").Value
PerfDate6 = Format(PerfDate6, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate6 = CDate(PerfDate6)

PerfDate7 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F7").Value
PerfDate7 = Format(PerfDate7, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate7 = CDate(PerfDate7)

PerfDate8 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F8").Value
PerfDate8 = Format(PerfDate8, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate8 = CDate(PerfDate8)

PerfDate9 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F9").Value
PerfDate9 = Format(PerfDate9, "MM/DD/YYYY")
'PerfDate9 = CDate(PerfDate9)

Now2 = CDate(Now() - 1) 'formatting the date using the CDate function
Now2 = Format(Now2, "MM/DD/YYYY") 'formatting the date by dropping the hour
'Now2 = CDate(Now2) 'formatting the date again

Now22 = CDate(Now() - 3) 'formatting the date using the CDate function
Now22 = Format(Now22, "MM/DD/YYYY") 'formatting the date by dropping the hour
'Now2 = CDate(Now2) 'formatting the date again

' Day 1 (Friday)
If PerfDate1 >= Now22 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day1").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate1)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day1").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 2 (Saturday)
If PerfDate2 >= Now22 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day2").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate2)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day2").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 3 (Sunday)
If PerfDate3 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day3").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate3)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day3").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 4 (Monday)
If PerfDate4 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day4").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate4)
    'Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day4").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 5 (Tuesday)
If PerfDate5 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day5").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate5)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day5").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 6 (Wednesday)
If PerfDate6 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day6").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate6)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day6").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 7 (Thursday)
If PerfDate7 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day7").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate7)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day7").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 8 (Friday)
If PerfDate8 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day8").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate8)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day8").Range("a1")
End If

' Day 9 (Saturday)
If PerfDate9 >= Now2 Then
    Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day9").Range("a:h").ClearContents
    Sheets("Data").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
         ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
      End If
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$G$12000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:= _
            xlFilterValues, Criteria2:=Array(2, PerfDate9)
    Range("A1:G1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Copy Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("Day9").Range("a1")
End If


''' Merge Days ''''

Workbooks("Book2").Sheets("DaysMerged").Range("a:h").ClearContents

' Day 1
Sheets("Day1").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A1:G1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A1")
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 2
Sheets("Day2").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then

Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 3
Sheets("Day3").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 4
Sheets("Day4").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 5
Sheets("Day5").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then

Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 6
Sheets("Day6").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then

Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 7
Sheets("Day7").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then

Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 8
Sheets("Day8").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then

Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select

Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

' Day 9
Sheets("Day9").Select
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
        ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    End If
Range("A2:G2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
If Last_Row > 1 Then
Selection.Copy
Sheets("DaysMerged").Select
Range("A1").Select
Last_Row = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

With Range("A" & Last_Row + 1)
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
      :=False, Transpose:=False
   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
      SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End With
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: `PerfDate9 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F1").Value` Should that be F9 ?

Comment: Yes that should be f9 forgot to change that one. i have now managed to get it part working, just trying to get it to merge together. i have edited the code with where i am but now getting 1004 error cant paste here because of the area size. is this because the sheet is empty at present if so how to fix, also is there a better way to improve this ?

Comment: I'm sure it can be simplified once I understand the task. *So on Sunday i can see Saturday* - if you have 10 days from yesterday (saturday) then surely you can see back to a thursday ?

Comment: There is a data dump that updates on a regular basis, this dump always goes from yesterday and forward so many days, i need to keep the data for each day for a week, so for instance on Monday i can no longer see Saturday, so need to keep Saturdays data, but then update Sunday to Friday, on Tuesday, keep Sat / Sun but update Mon to Fri and so forth. New dates will be entered for the next week to do this again so we can keep the weeks data. does this help ? Also updated with working code, so just need to make it quicker and prevent any issues that may arise. im still researching.

Comment: What is in cells F1 to F9 , are they formulas ?

Comment: Dates are in those cells.

Comment: I guessed that as you were assigning them to PerfDate1 etc, are they just 9  consecutive days starting with yesterday and are they entered manually or derived ? What is significance of Now22 being 3 days earlier than the macro run date ? Is the macro always run on the same day of the week ?

Comment: Ignore the Now22, that was just testing, that has been changed to the same as the rest, This code works fine now. just not the quickest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you have repeating blocks of essentially the same code, it makes sense to use a loop.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub LoadData()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wb2 As Workbook
    Dim wsDay As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim dt As Date, dtStart As Date, dow As String
    Dim n As Long, lastrow As Long, lastrow2 As Long
    Dim msg As String, t0 As Single: t0 = Timer
    
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    dt = wb.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F1")
    
    ' validate F1 cell entry
    dow = WeekdayName(Weekday(dt, vbMonday))
    If dow <> "Friday" Then
        MsgBox Format(dt, "dd mmm yyyy") & " is a " & dow & ", must be Friday", _
        vbCritical, "Dotcom cell F1"
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Set wb2 = Workbooks("Book2")
    
    ' update Day sheets
    With wb.Sheets("Data")
         ' find earlist date in data
         dtStart = WorksheetFunction.Min(.Columns("E:E"))
         If dtStart < dt Then
             MsgBox "Earliest date in Data is " & Format(dtStart, "dd mmm yyyy") & vbLf & _
             "which is before " & Format(dt, "dd mmm yyyy"), vbCritical, "Abort"
             Exit Sub
         End If
    
         If .AutoFilterMode = True Then .AutoFilterMode = False
         ' Day 1(Friday) to 9 (Saturday)
         For n = 1 To 9
            ' refresh present and future only
            If dt >= dtStart Then
                Set wsDay = wb2.Sheets("Day" & n)
                wsDay.UsedRange.Columns("A:H").ClearContents
                With .UsedRange.Columns("A:G")
                    .AutoFilter Field:=5, Operator:=xlFilterValues, _
                        Criteria2:=Array(2, Format(dt, "mm/dd/yyyy"))
                    .Copy wsDay.Range("A1")
                End With
                .AutoFilterMode = False
                msg = msg & vbLf & wsDay.Name & Format(dt, " dd mmm yyyy ") & _
                      WeekdayName(Weekday(dt, vbMonday), 1)
            End If
            dt = dt + 1
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox "Sheets refreshed " & msg, vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")
    t0 = Timer
    
    ' merge sheets
    Set ws2 = wb2.Sheets("DaysMerged")
    ws2.UsedRange.Clear
    
    lastrow2 = 1
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To 9
        With wb.Sheets("Day" & n)
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            If lastrow > 1 Then
                .Range("A2:G2").Resize(lastrow - 1).Copy
                With ws2.Range("A" & lastrow2)
                   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, _
                   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                   .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, _
                   Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
                End With
                lastrow2 = lastrow2 + lastrow - 1
            End If
            
        End With
    Next
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    MsgBox lastrow2 - 1 & " lines copied to " & ws2.Name, _
           vbInformation, Format(Timer - t0, "0.0 secs")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks looks really good and clean, where does it get the dates from i need to specify dates as we could have two sheets (2 weeks) also will this ignore the days if they have passed as it should only ever update yesterdays data till the end of week,

Comment: So is it possible to set a date? as would have this weeks sheet and next weeks sheet. as the days progress we would end up into week 2, which then we would create a sheet for the week after. and so on.

Comment: New sheet for each week, we have to archive the sheet at the end of the week, easier just to run from a set date so that we can specify.

Comment: sorry workbook not sheet.

Comment: Yes, i need this to work from specified dates not from days of the week. as i said the workbook will be created on a weekly basis and will have different dates. Hence the reason for me originally specifying the dates.

Comment: Its just 9 dates from a set date, start of the week is in F2 i,e  02 feb 23 F1 would be the day before so 01 Feb 23 then F3 - F9 would just be each day after 02 Feb 23. the data surely would be irrelevant other than the date which is what its filtering and then copying, the idea of this is to recreate the raw data sheet, saving data that is no longer available, as the data is only available from yesterday onwards, all old data must be saved but continue updating new.

Comment: it should start on a sat, but would need fri before to the following fri.

Comment: thanks again for looking, this runs very quick which is great, the date part is still not right. This needs to look at the date in F1 lets just assume that is Sat 16th Sept, Day 1 would be the 15th to Day 9 23rd. The sheet should update all data at first, On Sat it should still update the whole sheet, on Sun it should ignore first friday and run Sat (day 2) to following Sat (Day 9) on Sun it should ignore Fri and Sat but Update Sun (Day 3) to Sat (Day9) and so forth, the dates that dont get updated must keep data and be included in the merge.

Comment: @deathy It does that `dt = wb.Sheets("Dotcom").Range("F1")`. The message box tells you which sheets have been updated. You said start of the week is in F2 and start on a sat so F1 is a Friday